# Remove 'Custom..' option in tinyMCE colour swatch

Tags: wp-admin, tinymce, visual-editor

Is it possible to remove the 'Custom...' option in the editors colour picker to prevent the user adding custom colours?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to remove the custom colors option from tinyMCE.

WordPress bundles a tinyMCE plugin to handle the custom colors functionality. The `tiny_mce_plugins` filter can be used to remove this bundled plugin which is identified by the key `colorpicker`.

Note that removing the custom colors option will not affect users' ability to select colors using the default color swatches.

```
/**
 * Remove the Color Picker plugin from tinyMCE. This will
 * prevent users from adding custom colors. Note, the default color
 * palette is still available (and customizable by developers) via
 * textcolor_map using the tiny_mce_before_init hook.
 * 
 * @param array $plugins An array of default TinyMCE plugins.
 */
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'wpse_tiny_mce_remove_custom_colors' );
function wpse_tiny_mce_remove_custom_colors( $plugins ) {       

    foreach ( $plugins as $key => $plugin_name ) {
        if ( 'colorpicker' === $plugin_name ) {
            unset( $plugins[ $key ] );
            return $plugins;            
        }
    }

    return $plugins;            
}
```

Comment: This works great! Cheers